# Event data returns empty object in jquery when using "on()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delegation

I'm trying to use event delegation using "on()" for elements that are not presently available on the page. In this case i need to pass some data to "on()" function, which is a JSON object. The code for this looks as follows:

```
$(document).off('click',targetElement).on('click',targetElement,eventData,function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  console.log(e.data)
  });
```

My issue is that when this event is triggered e.data is returned as empty object and hence m not able to consume it.
I have built this code with reference API provided here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Can anyone please guide what is going wrong here?

P.S the target element is not on page. It gets rendered on some function call.

Comment: Unable to replicate; what you have works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvyy6mpL/ Can you please add a working demonstration of the problem to your question.

Comment: is this a part of your code? where do you define targetElement? Yo have to replace "targetElement" with proper ID of your object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in the fiddle that you provided the element was there in DOM. Try with creating the element dynamically and then binding it.

Comment: @user1481887 given that the code still uses a delegated event handler, that makes no difference.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour this binding declaration comes in another function which is getting called after element is inserted in DOM. But i think that should not matter when we use "on()" in this manner.

Comment: Can we pass object like this to event.data?:
`{resultelement: "#edit_lineitem_matching_popup .popUpTableHolder", parentelement: "#edit_lineitem_matching_popup", targetelement: "#edit_lineitem_matching_popup div.pagination-controls li > a"}`

Comment: Another observation. When i pass the above data in "on()" function and console.log the "e.data" on event i get:
`{targetelement: undefined}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you take a look at my previous 2 comments and advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try getting target element inside the fired function (using e.target) and then consume what you want:

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log($(e.target))
    });
```

Comment: How do i pull event data "e.data" in this?

Comment: Does e.target.innerHTML meet your need?

Comment: Nope. I need to have the JSON data that i will be passing to it

Comment: try console.log($(e.target)) this will return a complete array of event properties. you can extract what you want. post updated as well.